# How to get value from XML response from webmethod in c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

> "<"?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
>   "<"string xmlns=\"http://xyz.org/\">
>   Hello World
>   "<"/string>

I want to get Hellow World. Then What to do?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, you want write this xml in the response (you have to use response.write) or get this xml and use it (in this case you have to deserialise this string) ?

Comment: This is response of webmethod which i got. But how can i get only string 'Hellow World'?

Comment: It's just XML. Parse it with LINQ to XML.

Comment: Mmm i think he returns that to the client, so LINQ to XML is not an option in javascript

Comment: This is response of a web method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Result").click(function() {
     $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Default.aspx/MyWebMethod",
      data: "{}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(msg) {
         alert(msg.d);
      }
});
```